# No eclipse android, quando o emulador ficar em paisagem o programa não muda?

Tags: android, android-eclipse, emulador

No eclipse  android, quando  o emulador ficar em paisagem o programa não muda continua em retrato como resolver isso.

Comment: Poste um pouco do seu código para entendermos o que você tentou fazer.

Comment: Seria bom incluir o seu `AndroidManifest.xml`, se você colocou a tag `android:configChanges" é você quem precisa adaptar o layout, já que a `Activity` não esta sendo reconstruída. Dê uma olhada no método `onConfigurationChanged` para atualizar seu layout usando o `setContentView`.

Comment: @Wakim no aparelho físico funciona legal, porem no emulador não você aperta f11 ele muda para paisagem porém o app continua em retrato.

Comment: Acho que as vezes é bug do emulador, o método `onConfigChanges` é chamado? Aproveitando, para trabalhar com emulador/avd eu recomendo usar o Genymotion, que é muito mais rápido/fácil de usar que o avd.

Comment: @Wakim valeu pela dica vou testar Genymotion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que seja algum Bug mesmo. Também passo por esses problemas no Mac e no Windows.

Quando aperta F11, as vezes ele muda a orientação, as vezes não. Mas o problema só ocorre dentro da aplicação, pois quando estou na tela inicial do Android o problema não ocorre.

O mais correto é utilizar um aparelho físico para realizar os testes. Eu só utilizo o Emulador para simular diferentes tamanhos de tela.